# AJAX not working properly when submitting form

Tags: php, ajax

I don't know what's wrong. My validation works well, but when I hit the button to perform an AJAX call it isn't working the "normal way" using POST.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#loginSubmit").validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo("div#errors");
        },
        rules: {
            "username": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5

            },  
            "password": {
                required: true,
                minlenght: 5,
                maxlenght: 20

            }
        },
        messages: {
            "username": {
                required: "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Wprowadź poprawną nazwę użytkownika </div>",
                minlength: "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Wymagane minumum 3 znaki </div>"
            },  
            "password": {
                required: "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Wprowadź hasło </div>",
                minlength: "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Wymagane minimum 8 znaków</div>",
                maxlength: "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Wymagane maksymalnie 15 znaków</div>"
            }
        },
      submitHandler: submitForm
    });

function submitForm()
{
    var data = $("#loginSubmit").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'login.php',
        data : data, 
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#login-Submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; logowanie...');
        },
        success :  function(data)
        {
            if(data==1){

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry email already taken !</div>');

                    $("#login-Submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });

            }
            else if(data=="registered")
            {

                $("#login-Submit").html('Signing Up');
                setTimeout('$(".card-block").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".card-block").load("ADMIN/index.php"); }); ',5000);

            }
            else{

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                    $("#login-Submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });


            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

When I remove the validation code and refresh the page, the AJAX request starts but there are no results. I don't know why it does not start functioning by hitting the button.

Comment: srry for english,

Comment: Can you post the whole page, or a cut down version of the view that reproduces the problem?

Comment: kindly, put submitHandler: submitForm inside }) and then check again. Thanks.

Comment: how i can post another code to this question ?

Comment: if your question is related to the same as above or in connection the mention it here as comment otherwise create a new question

Comment: @user1544541 nothing happens,

Comment: can you send me the complete code with proper HTML in order to check where actually the problem is?

Comment: There is normal form, after this is this ajax js and login.php, but whatevere where what is, should start ajax and for example give some error or start over and over, so error have to be in this js, dunno